# MQTT Android keeps in Reconnecting state

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, exception, mqtt

I am trying to connect my android application with MQTT using AWS here is my code

```
mqttManager.connect(credentialsProvider, new AWSIotMqttClientStatusCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(AWSIotMqttClientStatus status, Throwable throwable) {
                Log.i("ConnectionResult", status.name());
            }


        });
```

But it keeps in these states 
Connecting..
Reconnecting

```
MqttException (0) - java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.String.toLowerCase()' on a null object reference
```

Comment: What version of SDK are you using?

Answer (score 0):

A fix for this was submitted in the following PR https://github.com/aws-amplify/aws-sdk-android/pull/612. I would recommend trying with the latest version (2.16.5 when this answer was first written). 
Also you can use the following sample app to check out how to connect to AWS IoT via Android SDK:
 https://github.com/awslabs/aws-sdk-android-samples/tree/master/AndroidPubSubWebSocket